# Seperation of Storing data and Outputting data

Tags: powershell

I have 2 functions, one for getting data and the other for outputting the data. These were split to allow for "refreshing" without having to make another request for static information.

I want the Get-AllAP function to make the request and store the data.

I want the Show-APAll function to take that data and output it.

The reason for this is so on "refresh" we can run Show-APAll and this will just output the data from the first request rather than making a whole other request.

```
function Get-AllAP {
    $functionName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand
    Write-Verbose "Function Start: Get-AllAP"
    Write-Log "Get-AllAp started for Store $Store" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile
    Write-Host "Getting all Access Points in Store $Store. This can take a moment."
    Write-Verbose "Getting all APs for Store $Store"
    $storeApReq = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
    Write-Verbose "Making request to $storeApReq"
    $global:apIdListReq = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $storeApReq -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
    Write-Log "Making Get request to $storeApReq" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile

    $global:apIdList =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
    $global:apIdCount =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"
    $global:controllerName = $apData.unifiedApInfo.controllerName
    $global:apIdURL =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
    $global:apURLs = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId | ForEach-Object -MemberName '@url'

    ## Create array object of all aps on site
    Write-Verbose "Creating Access Point loop"
    $global:apArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    Write-Host "Getting status on Access Points: " -NoNewLine

    ## Begin looping
    $global:apLoop = foreach ($apURL in $apURLs) {
        $apFullReq = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apURL'.json' -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
        $global:allApData = $apFullReq.queryResponse.entity.accessPointDetailsDTO

        ## Store our data
        $global:apStatus =$allApData.status
        $global:apName = $allApData.name
        $global:apPing = $allApData.reachabilitystatus
        $global:controllerName = $allApData.unifiedApInfo.controllerName
        $global:switch = $allApData.cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor[0].neighborName
        $global:switchPort = $allApData.cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor[0].neighborPort
        $global:location = $allApData.locationHierarchy
        $global:clientCount = $allApData.clientCount

        ## Watch for errors in loop
        Write-Host "$apName " -NoNewline

        ## Output apName to array for use later
        $apArray.Add($apName)
        Write-Log "$apName discovered with $clientCount devices connected." -Level DEBUG -logfile $logFile
    }
}
```

This function queries the API and gets the information on APs that we want to use later. Next it'll refer over to `Show-APAll` to display this data.

```
Function Show-APAll {
    $functionName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand
    Write-Log "Show-APAll started for Store $Store" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile
    Write-Verbose "Function start: Show-APAll"
    Clear
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host '-------------------------------------------' -Foregroundcolor "DarkCyan"
    Write-Host "    All Access Points For Store $Store"
    Write-Host '-------------------------------------------' -Foregroundcolor "DarkCyan"

    foreach ($apName in $apArray) {
        ## Print to log for debugging
        Write-Log "$apName discovered with $clientCount devices connected." -Level DEBUG -logfile $logFile

        ## Output data for user
        Write-Host " "
        Write-Host "AP Name: $apName"
        if ($apPing -eq 'UNREACHABLE') {
            Write-Host "AP is Offline" -Foregroundcolor "Red"
        } else {
            Write-Host "AP is Online" -ForegroundColor "Green"
        }
        if ($apStatus -eq 'Critical') {
            Write-Host "AP Problem Level:$apStatus" -Foregroundcolor "Red"
        } else {
            Write-Host "AP Problem Level: $apStatus" -ForegroundColor "Green"

        }
        Write-Host "Clients Connected: $clientCount"
        Write-Host "Location: $location"
        Write-Host "Switch Port: $switchPort on $switch"
    }
    Management-AfterAll
}
```

What's happening here, as I'm sure you can guess, is that only the `$apName` is unique, while the rest of the data is stored to the variable as the last object to be looped through. Here are some logs which show exactly what's occuring with the `$clientCount`.

Log output:

```
2018/09/04 08:39:42 INFO Making Get request to https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=0026 Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:42 DEBUG 0026AP4 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:43 DEBUG 0026AP7 discovered with 3 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:43 DEBUG 0026AP8 discovered with 0 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:43 DEBUG 0026AP3 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:44 DEBUG 0026AP9 discovered with 0 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:44 DEBUG 0026AP1 discovered with 9 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:44 DEBUG 0026AP6 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:44 DEBUG 0026AP10 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP2 discovered with 0 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP5 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Get-AllAP User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 INFO Show-APAll started for Store 0026 Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP4 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP7 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP8 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP3 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP9 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP1 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP6 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP10 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP2 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
2018/09/04 08:39:45 DEBUG 0026AP5 discovered with 1 devices connected. Function: Show-APAll User: admin-dksc104694
```

The `$clientCount` response values are fine in `Get-AllAp`, but only the value for the last AP to be looped is usable. I do understand why this is occurring, because obviously a variable can only have a single assignment in a given time, but I'm unsure how to fix this without creating a mess of loops.

I've tried a number of things including adding the data to `$apArray`, but this is creating a mess in the output and just returning the position in the array as an integer. Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Answer 1 Edit:**

```
    Function Get-AllAP {
        $functionName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand
        Write-Verbose "Function Start: Get-AllAP"
        Write-Log "Get-AllAp started for Store $Store" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile
        Write-Host "Getting all Access Points in Store $Store. This can take a moment."
        Write-Verbose "Getting all APs for Store $Store"
        $storeApReq = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
        Write-Verbose "Making request to $storeApReq"
        $Global:apIdListReq = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $storeApReq -method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
        Write-Log "Making Get request to $storeApReq" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile

        $apIdList = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
        $apIdCount = $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"
        $controllerName = $apData.unifiedApInfo.controllerName
        $apIdURL = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
        $apURLs = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId | ForEach-Object -MemberName '@url'  

        ## Create array object of all aps on site
        Write-Verbose "Creating Access Point loop"
        $Global:apArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        Write-Host "Getting status on Access Points: " -NoNewLine

        ## Begin looping
        foreach ($apURL in $apURLs) {
        $apFullReq = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "${apURL}.json" -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{Authorization = $auth}
        $allApData = $apFullReq.queryResponse.entity.accessPointDetailsDTO

        $apArray = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'apStatus'       = $allApData.status
            'apName'         = $allApData.name
            'apPing'         = $allApData.reachabilitystatus
            'controllerName' = $allApData.unifiedApInfo.controllerName
            'switch'         = $allApData.cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor[0].neighborName
            'switchPort'     = $allApData.cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor[0].neighborPort
            'location'       = $allApData.locationHierarchy
            'clientCount'    = $allApData.clientCount
        }

    }
}
```

This does help with making the data more PS friendly, and I can output the data, but this doesn't solve the problems outlined in my question.

1. Object properties still inaccessible to other functions without making Global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using global variables for everything. Create custom objects from the REST response and output them in the function, then collect the function output in a variable in the caller scope.

```
function Get-AllAP {
    ...

    $apIdList = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
    $apIdCount = $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"
    $controllerName = $apData.unifiedApInfo.controllerName
    $apIdURL = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
    $apURLs = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId | ForEach-Object -MemberName '@url'

    ...

    foreach ($apURL in $apURLs) {
        $apFullReq = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "${apURL}.json" -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{Authorization = $auth}
        $allApData = $apFullReq.queryResponse.entity.accessPointDetailsDTO

        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'apStatus'       = $allApData.status
            'apName'         = $allApData.name
            'apPing'         = $allApData.reachabilitystatus
            'controllerName' = $allApData.unifiedApInfo.controllerName
            'switch'         = $allApData.cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor[0].neighborName
            'switchPort'     = $allApData.cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor[0].neighborPort
            'location'       = $allApData.locationHierarchy
            'clientCount'    = $allApData.clientCount
        }
    }
}

$apArray = Get-AllAP
```

Add a parameter to the function `Show-AllAP` and pass the variable `$apArray` as an argument to the function:

```
function Show-AllAP {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [array]$apList
    )

    ...
    foreach ($ap in $apList) {
        Write-Host ('AP Name: {0}' -f $ap.apName)
        ...
    }
    ...
}

Show-AllAP $apArray
```

The point is not to avoid global variables entirely, but to avoid modifying (or even using) global variables in nested contexts. A well defined interface makes it clear to the reader what information (from the rest of your code) goes into the function, and what data is returned by the function (although PowerShell admittedly is a little fuzzy when it comes to the latter). Global variables in nested contexts are basically a side-channel in the data flow and usually make troubleshooting a lot more complicated, particularly when your code base grows.

The whole point of encapsulating code in functions is to provide an abstraction where you could change the implementation of the function as well as your global code (like rename your global variable) without one affecting the other. As long as the function interface (the parameter set and returned data) doesn't change, that is.

Comment: I agree, and @CodeSpent if you do not want to invoke the rest API every time you can easily export object arrays to CSV format for example with the `Export-Csv` cmdlet and load it when you need it with the `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: I admit the globals are lazy troubleshooting and once it worked I left it be. I think I definitely need to read up more on PSObjects and how I can leverage them. Trying this now.

@Christophe really the data only needs to be usable until the next request so I think it'll be okay to just store in a more temporary location for now.

Comment: In the end this just leaves me where I started but with a PSObject added to the mix. Without making variables Global Show-APAll cannot access this information and calling Get-AllAp from inside Show-APAll renders the split pointless anyways when I could just make it all one function again. I'm going to reopen and clarify in my question.

Comment: @CodeSpent Apparently my answer wasn't clear enough. Updated.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for your help. I'm just going to approve this because I do believe it answers the question, but not particularly in my use case with my current understanding. I'm going to revisit this after some research on how Powershell particularly handles passing information around. I'm finding I compare to often to JS. Furthermore I don't believe my use case fits typical PS utilization which I can see also convolutes things when asking for help.